# HyperV Type Clipboard Text does not work in Ubuntu 20.04 (or Linux in general)

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, ubuntu-20.04, windows-server-2022

I am using Hyper-V in Windows Server 2022.  I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 from ISO in Hyper-V.  Now, all I want to do is use the "Clipboard > Type Clipboard Text" command in HyeprV Connect.  Sadly, it does not work.  This has actually been bothering me for years and have had to manually type long strings into Linux VMs as a result of this.  Why Microsoft does not bother to make this "just work" out of the box for Linux like it does for Windows I will never know.

It was also my understanding that this was supposed to just work in Ubuntu, but it doesn't.  I have Enhanced Session Mode enabled in Hyper-V.

Does anyone know how to get this simple thing to work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://4sysops.com/archives/activate-enhanced-session-mode-for-ubuntu-vms-in-hyper-v/